# Getting "Cannot assign value of type 'CLLocationDegrees' (aka 'Double') to type 'Int'" error (Swift 4)

Tags: swift, mapkit

> The Error: "Cannot assign value of type 'CLLocationDegrees' (aka
>   'Double') to type 'Int'"

I am getting an error that says "Cannot assign value of type 'CLLocationDegrees' (aka 'Double') to type 'Int'". Below is an image of the error. When I make the recommended change (shown the second picture) it makes latitude, longitude, and speed an integer (whole number). I need the number to be as accurate as possible, so an integer is not accurate enough. Please reply if you have any questions or have a fix.

[The first picture with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jAE6.png)

[The second picture with the recommended fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vf75X.png)

Comment: The problem is that you declared your variables wrong. You made `latitudeCurrentLocation` etc. an Int.

Comment: What did you try to do? Did you search before you ask? possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42364537/how-to-fix-cannot-assign-value-of-type-cllocationdegrees-aka-double-to-ty

Comment: Don't post pictures of code. Post the actual code, and quote the error you're getting.

Comment: The recommended fix from Xcode is wrong. You should declare your `latitude` and `longitude` variables as CLLocationDegrees type, and `speedCurrentLocation` as a `Double`

Comment: @BurakÖztürk I don't think it is it that one seems slightly different. That one was with the Google Maps API. The problem was the same, but the solution was not. Thanks for understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare your variables as `CLLocationDegrees` type:

```
var latitudeCurrentLocation: CLLocationDegrees = 0.0
var longitudeCurrentLocation: CLLocationDegrees = 0.0
var speedCurrentLocation: CLLocationDegrees = 0.0
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked, but I had to make a few changes. I was using a variable, so I had to make it `var latitudeCurrentLocation: CLLocationDegrees = 0.0` and defined the variable as `latitudeCurrentLocation = location.coordinate.latitude`. Then do this for the rest of the variables. It would be great if you could update your answer for other people looking at this.